# How to call api using load balancer IP in Oracle cloud?

Tags: java, ajax, tomcat, load-balancing, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have created one instance on oracle cloud and attached to load balancer i have generated ssl certificate and in DNS record i have added load balancer IP, now when i am opening site in browser it's calling from load balancer IP.
Now In backend part my API is on tomcat server and it's calling using instance load balancer IP.(HTTP)
So when i am opening site in browser it show me  error as below

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.example.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://111.111.111.111:8080/shml/view/count'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

So i want to call API using using HTTPS. even i am adding Load balancer IP in xml configuration it is not calling using load balncer IP.

Is there any setting we can add in XML file so it can call from load balancer?
Or we can add any rule in oracle cloud load balancer related this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This error, as far I understand, is generated in the navigator, because you have a call to another service non-secure. Or do you mean that your 111.111.111.111 is the balanced address? Or, other wise, if the call XMLHttpRequest  is generated by your code, indicate that generate with HTTPS and canonical DNS name.

Comment: 111.111.111.111 is instance public ip address.

Comment: Ok, then check who and how is generating the unsafe call in your page to the unsafe page.